Why Does a Changing $B$ field Produce a Circular (or elliptical depending on the density of change) $E$ field?
I have just finished my first year university class in EM and was left wondering as to why induced $E$ field specifically have a circular direction when caused by a straight, changing $B$ field? Also why does a current cause a circular $B$ field? I can see this answer through elementary RHR but would like a deeper understanding; or maybe this is just observed?.

in addition to @JEB's answer below you can read more about Ignatowski's equations here and here.

A changing magnetic field doesn't induce an electric field. The electric and magnetic field at an event $(t, \vec r)$ are only caused by charges, currents, and their time derivatives on the past light-cone. See: Jefimenko's equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations).
Although the idea of "induction" is incredibly useful for designing motors, generators and other EM devices, it is fundamentally unsound regarding causation; rather, Jefimenko's equations show that the fields at an event will always satisfy Maxwell's equations, specifically:
$$ \dot{\vec{B}} \propto \vec{\nabla}\times
\vec{E} $$
but that in no way means $B$ is causing $E$.
The next level of deeper understanding requires a descent level of understanding special relativity. For instance: a stationary charge has and electric field:
$$ \vec E \propto \frac{\hat r}{r^2} $$
and
$$ \vec B = 0 $$
but for someone moving with respect to the charge, there is a non-spherically symmetric electric field, and a non-zero magnetic field.
The next step is figure why the magnetic field can be described by a vector potential:
$$ \vec B = \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A} $$
and the electric field picks up a time-dependent correction to it's voltage:
$$ \vec E = -\vec{\nabla}\phi + \dot{\vec A} $$
(Even here, you can see that it is $\dot{\vec A}$ causing both the electric field and the change in the magnetic field, and it is cause by currents).
From there, you may ask yourself why both the magnetic field and the Coriolis force can be described as the curl of a vector potential.
The next step to deeper understanding is to go relativistic, where:
$$ A^{\mu} = (\phi, \vec A) $$
(note, I am setting $c=1$ throughout), and the electromagnetic field tensor is:
$$ F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - 
\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu} $$
and
$$  \partial_{\mu} F^{\mu\nu} = j^{\nu} $$
with the 4-current:
$$ j^{\nu} = (\rho, \vec j) $$
Note:
$$ \partial^{\nu} = (\frac d{dt}, \vec{\nabla}) $$
So there is clearly some 4-dimensional non-euclidean geometry afoot.
At this point, you may notice that physics doesn't depend on $A^{\mu}$, because it's all invariant under:
$$ A^{\mu} \rightarrow A^{\mu} + \partial^{\mu}\chi $$
where $\chi$ is any differentiable Lorentz scalar field.
That's pretty deep, and leads to people talking about connections on fiber bundles tangent to the manifold, Gauge invariance, and the Lagrangian formulation which allows a local $U(1)$ symmetry of the charge particle's phase leading to the connection $A^{\mu}$, that is: a gauge symmetry means charge is conserved and Maxwell's Equation must exist (as it is a minimumly coupled 4-vector field--see "Representation Theory of the Lorentz Group", where EM is the $(\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$ representation).
If you look at recents PSE questions, this is all captured in the Anharov-Bohm experiment, where the ultimate deep understanding you desire is captured in the statement:
"Electromagnetism is nothing more than an un-integratabtle phase"
to whom I have forgotten the citation.

thanks for the detailed response, I often get told by professors that "You will learn this material later in your physics degree" so its very helpful to have this to strengthen my understanding now and to see which areas of math I need to self learn in order to do so!

@giladjankelowitz There is a great explanation of your conundrum here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2yIkDVs0cA
